# Merge two Partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

[image]

How to merge the E drive with the unallocated drive without loosing data in E.

Comment: Look here: http://superuser.com/questions/243314/claim-space-for-a-partition-from-another-partition-nearby

Comment: "Unallocated" is not a real partition, just empty (unallocated) space, so you don't need to "merge" anything - just extend the E: partition.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a GParted live cd. GParted is free and works.

Here is a link to a tutorial for using [gparted live cd on windows partitions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/).

I used this same method on my wife's computer recently to accomplish almost the same thing.

If all you have on partition e: are files you shouldn't have to repair the system when you reboot. If all goes well it should be a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

To resize the partition, use GParted.

An easy way is to get Ubuntu, put it on a CD or USB pen drive, boot it, and use Partition Editor.

Ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download

Partition Editor:
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

There is also a GParted live CD you can use: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't.  You could do it if the unallocated space were "behind" E (by extending E).  Unfortunately you're in the opposite situation.  So the only way is to backup E, destroy E, recreate a larger partition, name it E and restore the contents.

Comment: Is it possible by using 3rd party software like "Partition Magic".

Comment: Yes (defunct) partition magic can "Move" partitions. It can automate the tasks I've described.

Comment: Definitely backup E, first.

Comment: Couldn't he extend his D drive? That way he could make use of the space.

Comment: @Mugen, my answer is wrong. Gparted does this kind of shift very easily.  Since this outdated post, I've done similar things and it does work.  I'll delete this "shameful" answer in a while ;-)

Comment: no please wait. do you have a link as to how we can do this? I need to extend my main partition (C drive). I have booted using Gparted but cannot add space to my partition using "move/resize". And I don't think theres anything "shameful" here. :)

Comment: @Mugen, for partitions, every case is special, is there a place where you could upload a screenshot of the disk manager or better Gparted's display? If your config is similar to the one shown by the OP, you should be able to drag "E" on the right hand side to fill up the unallocated space and stick to "D". Are you meeting some resistance when trying to do this?

Comment: Actually both the partitions are on two different physical disks. I'm not sure, is it possible to combine them to a single partition? I have c on one hard disk and d on another.

Comment: The only way to have a partition spanning two different disks is by having an underlying raid-set. I wouldn't advise this for a normal PC user.  Without a raid-set, this is not possible. Just remember that the partition map of a given disk is located in its MBR. Browse through [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) to get a clear picture of how it works in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Do Not use Partition Magic.

Do use Partition Wizard.

I've recommended this solution to many Win 7 users.

I've used Parition Wizard to do exactly what you ate trying to do.

Burn the iso to a CD and boot from the CD.

Win win 7 you can burn an iso to cd/dvd by simply clicking on the iso file (as long as you haven't changed the default assignment for iso files).

http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html